# Allowing non domain user to query Active Directory

Tags: windows, web, active-directory, novell

Our developers have recently built a new internal 'image viewer' application for our staff to use. The image viewer runs as a website and uses Active Directory to authenticate the user and control what type of images that user is allowed to view.

I have this setup and working fine by running the website as an impersonated domain user. The problem I now face is that all the images are held on a non-domain share. How can I access this share using the domain user? The share is on a Novell Netware 6.5 server.

Alternatively I can run the website as a non-domain user and connect to the Netware server to retrieve the images, but then I am unable to query Active Directory.

Can I allow a non-domain user access to query AD? I don't wish to allow anonymous queries on my domain controllers.

Answer (score 0):

No, a non-domain user cannot query Active Directory unless you configure your domain to [allow anonymous queries](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320528).

Depending on how everything is setup in the web application, you may be able to insert some code to switch security contexts and impersonate a domain user at the point where the query happens.